# How to enable the passwordless login like Slack is redirecting to Home Screen after the user clicks on Verify Email Link using Firebase Auth?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I just want to send a Verify Email Link to End User. Once the user clicks on the link if Application installed it will redirect to the Home Page. This is how Slack Mobile has giving seamless user experience.

This is the Firebase method to send the Email Verification with ActionCode Settings.

Here is my Swift implementation:

```
 @objc func didTapNext() {
     let actionCodeSettings =  ActionCodeSettings()
     actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
     let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
     actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: String(format: "https://drawrect.page.link/?link=https://storiesnow.company&apn=com.example.android&amv=3&ibi=storiesnow.companyNow&isi=1234567&ius=storiesnowapp"))
     actionCodeSettings.dynamicLinkDomain = "storiesnow-17495.firebaseapp.com"
     actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
     user!.sendEmailVerification(with: actionCodeSettings) { (error) in
       if (error != nil) {
         // Error occurred. Inspect error.code and handle error.
        return
         }
       // Email verification sent.
       print("verification email sent")
       print("action code setting URL is: \(String(describing: actionCodeSettings.url))")
        }
    }
```

But when I click on the link from the Email client. It gives me an error.

> Invalid Dynamic Link - Blocked

[image: Invalid Dynamic Link Error Screenshot]

Is the whitelisted domain required to enable this feature? Or without having the domain also possible to enable this feature.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth#send_an_authentication_link_to_the_users_email_address